# Type Check using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code that reads a spreadsheet that is filled with procedures that will be carried out by workers and divides them into "shifts" based on the duration of each activity so that preparation for certain steps can be made before.

I am looking for some help, as if someone inputs text that is not an integer (a note or something) into the "duration" tab, (which is stored as **`"X"`** in this code) the macro stops prematurely.

I was thinking I could use an if statement to check this, perhaps the **`"IsNumeric()"`** function, but it would not run and I knew I was not doing it correctly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'define variables
Dim duration As Integer, n As Long, i As Integer, x As Integer, m As Long
Dim toolRange As Range, partRange As Range, perRange As Range, workRange As Range, ppeRange As Range

n = 3 'indicates row
m = 3 'concatenation counter
duration = 0 'duration counter
x = 0 'duration placeholder

For i = 1 To 100 'Assumed max 50 shifts (This can be changed or solved with more code, but should be set higher than predicted # of shifts)

    duration = 0 'resets duration for next count

        While duration < Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(6, "K").Value 'shift length can be altered

            x = Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(n, "F").Value
                    duration = duration + x 'adds duration until it is over 320
                    n = n + 1
        Wend

    With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
        Set toolRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "H"), .Cells(n, "H")) 'creates tool range
    End With

    With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
        Set partRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "I"), .Cells(n, "I")) 'creates part range
    End With

    With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
        Set perRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "E"), .Cells(n, "E")) 'creates per range
    End With

    With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
        Set workRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "P"), .Cells(n, "P")) 'creates permit range
    End With

    With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
        Set ppeRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "Q"), .Cells(n, "Q")) 'creates ppe range
    End With

    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = i 'creates shift
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Application.Max(perRange) 'creates max per
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = duration 'creates duration
    'Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = ConcatenateAllCellValuesInRange(toolRange) 'inputs tools
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = ConcatUniq(toolRange, " ") 'inputs tools
    'Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ConcatenateAllCellValuesInRange(partRange) 'inputs parts
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = ConcatUniq(partRange, " ") 'inputs parts
    'Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = ConcatenateAllCellValuesInRange(workRange) 'inputs permits
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = ConcatUniq(workRange, " ") 'inputs permits
    'Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = ConcatenateAllCellValuesInRange(ppeRange) 'inputs ppe
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = ConcatUniq(ppeRange, " ") 'inputs ppe
    m = n 'Allows it to segement down page


Next i 'goes to next shift

End Sub

'Concatenate function
Function ConcatUniq(ByRef rng As Range, _
    ByVal myJoin As String) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Static dic As Object
    If dic Is Nothing Then _
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each r In rng
        dic(r.Value) = Empty
    Next
    ConcatUniq = Join$(dic.keys, myJoin)
    dic.RemoveAll
End Function
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Val function to get the numeric part of a string. Val will also return 0 if the value is not numeric or empty string. You could combine this with IsNumeric in your While condition.

```
Dim vVal As Variant
Dim nVal As Long

vVal = Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(6, "K").Value
nVal = Val(vVal)

While duration < nVal && IsNumeric(vVal)
    ...
Wend
```

References:

- [Val Function - VBA](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Val-Function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603)
- [IsNumeric Function - VBA](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/IsNumeric-Function-67795d2f-e53e-47a3-b107-c39df0ae2559)